# Erase disk and install Ubuntu on 2 hards

Tags: system-installation

I want to install ubuntu on my pc as my main system not alongside windows, i have 2 hards an sdd and an hdd

i want to do same like windows to make the sdd as the system disk, and the hdd for other data

so i came to this Erase disk and install Ubuntu, what should happend after ?

Comment: If you want to install Ubuntu on the SSD as the only OS and put the /home partition on the HDD use `something else` when installing and select a partition on the SSD for `/` and pick a partition on the SSD for `/home`.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are talking about the installer process. When this "erase disk" question comes up, you should select - if possible - the /dev/sda partition and continue.
Ubuntu will be installed, but you won't see your second hdd disk - since it is not formatted for Linux -yet.

After reboot you should install "gparted" with `sudo apt install gparted`.
Open it afterwards as any other program - you will have to enter your user password.

Select the disk you need to format:(in this is example the hdd is located under /dev/sdb)

[image: Gparted screenshot]

Now you can partition and format it, using the **ext4** format. When it can be mounted manually. Or add it to your /etc/fstab - there are many answers explaining the last two steps - hope it helped you to get on the way..